# LED Parallel Forward Voltage Higher Than Indvidual LEDs Vf

Tags: led, current-measurement, current-source, voltage-measurement, constant-current

I measured the forward voltage of two CoB LEDs at 600mA then wired them in parallel driven by 1200mA.

Why is the parallel V<sub>f</sub> higher than the individual forward voltages?

Forward Voltages:

```
Only LED1 @ 600mA      33.4V
Only LED2 @ 600mA      34.2V
Parallel @ 1200mA      34.9V
```

### Test Circuit

Driver is Constant Current Mean Well 60 Watt, 54 Volt, 1200mA.

---

Two measurements were made with 1200ma flowing through the paralleled pair of LEDs.

LEDs were mounted to a large copper heatsink.  Measurements were made immediately before LEDs got hot.

Measurement 1. As shown the current measured through the shunt resistor is for both LEDs.

Measurement 2.  When the switch is flipped, it measures only the current through LED1 yet current is still supplied to both.

The current through LED2 = measurement 1 - measurement 2

The voltage drop across the shunt (0.010V) is negligible when compared to the V<sub>f</sub> of about 35V.

**Results:**
I<sub>BOTH</sub> = 1231 mA
I<sub>LED1</sub> = 768mA
I<sub>LED2</sub> = 463mA (BOTH MINUS 1)

---

[image]

### Why I ask

On a cannabis forum the stoners do not know how electricity works.  They have a sub-forum just for LED grow lighting which includes building DIY fixtures.

I design LED grow lights. On this forum its the blind leading the blind.  It is my position that CoBs and strings of LEDs should never be driven in parallel with a CC driver with out load balancing.  When I state this I get a lot of opposition from uninformed members.

To prove my point I ran this test.  I was surprised that the parallel forward voltage was higher than the forward voltage of both LEDs when they were separately driven alone.

This is not something that needs to be fixed.  I just cannot explain why the parallel forward voltage would be higher than both of the individual forward voltages.

Comment: You must be aware of Schockley Effect and a test method to measure Tjcn by pulsing off the current and measure the low Vf at some uA level.  Were all measurements done at the same junction temp?  Can you estimate the temp from your tests?

Comment: Your circuit is wrong for the measurement you are trying to make. LED2 is either through the shunt or not through the shunt, but both LEDs always draw current. Put a shunt resistor in series with each LED and measure the current in each LED.

Comment: Did you you actually test 1 LED at a time?  Then 2 at a time shares the 40W or 20W each then cooler means less shift down in Vf

Comment: @JackCreasey I clarified the measurement description.  When the switch is flipped, it measures only the current through LED1 yet current is still supplied to both.   Flipping the switch would have negligible  influence on current flow through the LEDs because the shunt voltage is magnitudes less than the forward voltage,  0.0045 vs 34.9V.

Comment: why does 9mV/1400mA = 7.5 mohm yet schematic says 15 mohm?  Yet you dont explain config to measure different Vf for each LED.   For Vf1 and Vf2 is it 40W on 1 COB at a time?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes LED1 and LED2 forward voltages were measured alone at 600mA.  With a large heatsink and measurements were taken immediately upon power on before LEDs could get hot.  The forward voltages for CoBs used will decrease about 0.96V as temp changes from 25°C to 85°C.  All measurements were made around the same case temperature which was less than 50°C.

Comment: How did you apply 600mA to one LED with a Meanwell 1.2Acc supply?  You didn't say or show how you measured this so we doubt your results.  Also case temp of LED is not the same as Tjcn nor the same as heatsink temp.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Individual Vf was simply measured separately at about 20W each.  In parallel the watts were 20.5 W and 21W. Config for individual Vf was shunt and LED in series @ 600mA.  Fixed typo on shunt voltages.  Values were for another shunt. The HLG-60H-54A has an adjustment for Iout 0.69 ~ 1.2A. Thermal resistance junction to case is 0.23 W/°C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68919/discussion-between-tony-stewart-ee-since-75-and-misunderstood).

Comment: The junction thermal time constant is faster much than the case time constant and only takes  << 1 second.  Accurate Vf results must be done with a pulse only at a fixed temp.  So was it 0.69A or 0.6A? with a single LED?  What else are you not telling us?

Comment: Sorry but you said 1 LED is 600mA and I asked how, then you said meanwell can be regulated down to 0.69A which would imply a hotter LED and lower voltage. Hence I doubted your methods.  Curb your tongue pls. It does not look good on anyone.

Comment: I can expain how to use a diode or array as a thermistor to read junction temp using oven measurements and compare with pulsed x mA levels but the answer to your Question is a change in junction temp. (period)

Comment: @Misunderstood Using your 690mA test you can choose matched pairs directly from a selection of  resistors 0.1 Ohm and jumpers or exact value .  Falstad simulation http://tinyurl.com/y7vxk4c9 (safe)

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The question was WHY is the Vf higher when there is an imbalance.  Not how to fix imbalance.  I do not use CoBs and when driving multiple strips I use a driver for each strip.  If you read the Why in my question it states my stance is that CoBs (and strips) should not be connected in parallel. My experiment was to show why CoBs should not be connected in parallel.  My results were called into question when the parallel Vf was higher than the two individual Vf.  I am having a PCB fabed  to test the Texas Instruments LM3466 which balances CC loads.

Comment: I understood, all along, but I was hoping to explain how ESR is useful to see your answer or choose any Rs to match instantly and can also answer  other questions like the criteria for avoiding thermal runaway without active balancing.  But you said LED's dont have ESR. ( capiche?) That proved it

Comment: To your weed growers, I could tell this: If they want to power two or more COB LEDs on one supply (to save on power supply cost) they must not use a constant current but constant voltage adjustable SMPU. They must adjust the voltage just under typical voltage (maybe 1V less, but that must be tested). The LEDs will shine less but they will all run at less or much less than typical current. Say 400 or 500 mA instead of 600 mA. Like this they avoid overcurrent at the unbalanced COB LEDs.

Comment: They might need to add one or two more COB LED to compensate with the lack of light, but that's still the cheapest solution vs. current regulators or individual supplies. Reducing voltage will greatly reduce current and the risk of over-current and increase the LED longevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure each individual CoB LED Vf and your CC LED driver module can be adjusted to 690 mA, then I suggest the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foj2sL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can now measure the Vf for the CoB LEDs separately and somewhat more accurately based in current and temperature.

You could even (for a short time) remove R2 and from this get some idea of the slope of the Vf at 600 mA and then 690 mA.

If the voltage difference of your CoB modules are more than 0.5 - 2 V then I'd assume your current balance is going to be off by a large margin.

**Final solution**

Let's just for an example assume that your modules do come out at the numbers you proposed in the question:
LED1 @ 600mA      33.4V
LED2 @ 600mA      34.2V

What you need to do is to raise the voltage on the lower voltage module by 34.2 - 33.4 --> 0.8 V

If you place a 1.2 Ohm resistor (Use 1-2 W) in series with LED1 you will approximately balance the current flows through the two modules. This won't accurately track with module temperatures but it should get you within 10% or better current balance.

If your modules come out at different Vf values then you can calculate the balance resistor required.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not looking for a fix, just an explanation as to why the parallel Vf is higher than the Vf of individual LEDs.  This was an unexpected result.  I guessed the parallel Vf would be the lower 33.4V  Added "Why I ask" to post.  BTW I specialize in horticulture grow lights.  Efficiency is very important when electricity bill run $5,000+.  One rule is the LED current cannot flow through a resistor.  Efficiency of the driver is dependent on the DC resistance of the inductor I cannot justify resistors.  Also TI has a balance IC just for this purpose, an LM3466.

Comment: The reason the parallel Vf is higher is because the currents are unbalanced. The module with the higher current (and the lower Vf for your measurement) ends up with a higher Vf (the slope of the string ESR). The resistor in the example I gave dissipates less than 1 W .... if you used an LM3466 it would dissipate EXACTLY the same power!! The only difference with the LM3466 is that balancing multiple strings is easier to design ....but they still balance by using a FET a variable resistor.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the COB is xPyS (xy array) of LEDs then.
$$V_f = V_{knee} + I_f*ESR$$.  From the VI curve you can estimate the ESR.

I just computed your LED curve for you.

$$ESR=ΔV/ΔI=+6[V]/1.5[A]=4 \Omega $$
$$Vf= 32[V] +  If*4\Omega  $$ ,  thus Vf increases with current hogging.

Pd=Vf*If

Temp Rise=   Pd* Rja. {steady-state}
Vknee (vs Temp) =-4mV/‘C  ( -ve shift in Vf slightly like all diode thermometers)    ( verify  in spec)

Although LED datasheets dont list voltage at knee or Vk as they do in Zeners, the Vk tolerance is very tight due to the doping consistency  but the intermetallic tolerances are wide which affects ESR. Although one wafer can produce tolerances of ESR and thus Vf < 1% many wafers mixed together to produce a large batch are binned and into 0.1 increments or as required.  "open bin" can be as much as +/-50% unless the process is very tight. (well-controlled, high-quality)

$$ESR=k Pd $$ for k, my figure of merit constant **k=0.25** (best power LEDs) to k=1 for poor or low efficacy or tiny junctions as a  worse case) for Tjcn=85’C This constant is not published anywhere and is my observation over decades of reviewing all types of LEDs.{although 25’C used in some datasheets, Cree has started using 85'C}

This is expected to be lower slightly in future decades with design improvements but also ESR slowly reduces in the linear range as current increases.  Then rises again well above steady power limits in pulse mode at much lower efficacy.
{rare to exceed these limits}

———-

The better method is to ovenize the LED and measure the Vth with << 10% of rated power then during normal use pulse the LED down to that current level and measure the Vth shift due to the Shockley Effect.

This is the best method for explaining how Vf changes in different tests at the same current.

The only other permanent shift that can cause a change in Vf is a microscopic shunt R defect that fuses open which then causes the Vf to rise slightly.  This is a common defect found in power arrays during burn-in and caused by microscopic conductor particles in the semiconductor.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79678/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-older-than-dirt-led-parallel-forward-volta).

Answer (score -2):

@JackCreasey answered my question in the comments to his answer.

I had neglected to account for the rise in V<sub>f</sub> for the unbalanced CoB that was drawing 768 mA.

Also I was mistaken that the combined parallel V<sub>f</sub> would be determined by the LED with the least V<sub>f</sub>.  It is the LED with highest V<sub>f</sub> that determines the parallel V<sub>f</sub>.

It is the LED (LED<sub>1</sub>) with the lowest V<sub>f</sub> that draws more current when the LEDs are imbalanced.

The CoBs were Lumiled Fresh Focus Red Meat L2C5-RM001208E1500.

The individual and parallel LED<sub>1</sub> V<sub>f</sub> fall on the IV curve just where they are supposed to.

33.4V @ 600 mA
34.9V @ 768 mA

[image]

---

> This is the best method for explaining how Vf changes in different
>   tests at the same current.
> - TonyStewartolderthandirt

Except the currents were not the same.  600 mA, 768 mA, and 463 mA are not the same.

> Assuming the COB is xP by 10S LEDs the Vf = Vth(at 25'C and low
>   current) +If*ESR. From the VI curve you can estimate the ESR.
> - TonyStewartolderthandirt

The following photo is for @TonyStewartolderthandirt so he can count the dice for determining "xP by 10S" strings for whatever inconceivable reason that it may have any bearing on the question.

Not sure why I would want to find ESR when I am measuring and looking for V<sub>f</sub> on the IV curve.

[image]

Comment: The are consequences for unstable “negative feedback” above. But I can advise you that Vt like Vzt in zeners will be near identical and ESR can be estimated with expected tolerance on Vf is mainly if not always due to ESR variance and Vt response to temperature is the Shockley Effect about -4mV/‘C. You can expect to raise the best COB’s ESR to match the worst and thus have matched impedance (ESR) , Vf and share equal If if they are thermally matched (shared sink). I use my own formula to correct these ESR’s with a quick pulse test from 20%to 100% where Vzt in zeners is defined in a similar way

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt  Schockly Effect? Or negative temperature coefficient? Schockly field effect transistors?   I do not manufacture the CoBs, I buy them.  They come with their own Vf of which I have no control.  I will never understand why you prefer to convert Vf to ESR it is a wasted effort as all datasheets use Vf.    I repeat "Please NEVER reply to anything I ever post on this forum!!!  Word salad!!!  Useless word salad.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt RE: The are consequences for unstable “negative feedback” above. _____ It is not intended to be negative feedback, I am just responding to your answer.  It's just that you post such outrageous word salad BS and I have previously asked you NOT to comment on my posts.  To you it's negative feedback,  to me it's an honest response but also in hopes that you will not comment with your BS in the first place.   I posted a picture to give you something to do other than make silly comments. Vt Vtz?? E God! Don't go away mad just please go away. Pleazzzzzzz!

Comment: It seems you unwilling to learn. Go read a zener spec

Comment: No I am very willing to learn.  Why read a zener spec? What does a zener spec have to do with an LED?  Is that related to Vtz?   You do that a lot, you throw out a term and expect others to know what you mean.  I have kindly asked you to explain things in terms others can understand.  Dazzle.  Do not baffle. Too many times others believe you when you baffle with BS.  When I do understand what you are saying then I know it is wrong.  It's not that I am unwilling to learn it is that you are unable to teach.  You cannot fool all the people all the time.

Comment: @Misunderstood I have to agree with both of you. Tony has a long history of word sallad and throwing out semi-related hints. He did have a point however that your initial assumption was based on a flawed measurement.

Comment: In your world it my “word salad” is foreign to you,  but I am used to communicating root cause faults to similar experts in my field. My fault for not defining “common terms” with my former colleagues. Your fault for wrongly accusing me its gibberish, not asking me to expand or doing self-learning to comprehend e.g. Zzt in zeners is identical to ESR in LEDs (yet not published in table, rather computed from linear curve)

Comment: @winny Here's the thing about that measurement flaw, it does not exist.  My incorrect assumption was that the LED with the lower Vf would pull down the higher Vf when connected in parallel.