# I have 3.1V LED 20mA and wire 20 or more

Tags: power-supply, led, wiring, calculus

How you calculate how much Volt battery you need?

Like:

20 x 3.1V = 62V

....or is it something else?

I want to wire them in series manner.

Comment: Your math to estimate required voltage is correct, however when you go shopping, bear in mind using 10S2P or 5S4P for 31V, 30mA or 15.5V, 60mA should work about as well, so you have options.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the combined VF for the LEDs adds when connected in series to give you 62V for 20 LEDs. This is of course only approximate as the LEDs will vary slightly.

HOWEVER, you need to provide current limiting for the LEDs by either using a constant current power supply, or some current limiting device if you use a battery.

Since you seem to be using a battery solution I'd suggest you consider a simple linear constant current device like the [AL5809-20](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL5809.pdf) (less than $0.50c each 10 off). This is a simple two terminal device that sets a constant current through a string of LEDs and you can use a simple power supply or battery.

The device comes in various current levels designated by the last two digits of the part number:

[image]

To use them you simply connect as you would a resistor, and it sets the current for the string. You need to supply a slightly higher voltage because of the CC device. The overall efficiency is quite high because of minimal voltage drop across the device.

The recommended minimum voltage is 2.5V but the device will work down to a minimum overhead voltage of 1.75V.

[image]

You would then be able to use a higher voltage such as 2 - 6 LiPo cells in series to provide the power (and they are rechargeable). 
For example if you used 5S than you have a minimum of 5*3.6=18V and a maximum of 5*4.2=21V. With your LED forward voltages in the in the 3.1V range you could get 5 LEDs in each string with an ALS5809-20.

If you want to be really creative you could use a single LiPo cell (3.6 - 4.2V) and a boost DC-DC convertor (there are many on Ebay etc) to get say 20-50V and connect up to 15 LEDs in each string. The ALS5809 is limited to 60V, so you could easily support strings of 20 LEDs and it has to standoff only a small portion of the voltage. If you were to go above 60V I'd put a small resistor in parallel with the ALS5809 just in case (say 10kOhm).

An example of a very cheap Ebay converter is [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Boost-Converter-3-3v-5v-9v-12v-2A-Adjustable-Step-Up-Power-Supply-Module/112468350952?hash=item1a2fa2d7e8:g:HMIAAOSwec9ZsKkw:rk:6:pf:0), and you could go from a single LiPo cell (3.6-4.2V) to 28VDC allowing strings of 8 LEDs to be run.

Comment: Using a CCR is a great option for a simple current limiter.  That is when the supply is a constant CV or driving a single 20 mA LED with a battery.  I do not recommend serial Li-ion batteries as they get mismatched when charging.  When you get into the 5 or more LEDs in serial strings, you would need at least 5 Li-ion batteries for them to discharge to 3V each.  5 series Li-ion is far from ideal and too inefficient at full charge.  In this case a 4P5S combination with 80 mA is fine.  Samsung and Bridgelux do it all the time with mid power LEDs.  Serial/Parallel is okay  with low power LEDs.

Comment: @Misunderstood Thanks, that's why I suggested the CCR with a boost converter and a single LiPo cell. While the CCR is $0.40 - 0.50, it is well worth it for the simplicity. The Boost converters modules based on MT3608 are ridiculously cheap at $0.40 - 0.60 each, and I've made several higher voltage (therefore lower wiring current) strip lights in this manner.  Moving to 21-25V LED string voltage with 6 LED series groups allows me to use simple Cat6 Ethernet cable.

Comment: If you use a CC boost, the CCR is not needed.

Comment: @Misunderstood Not so IMO. If you have multiple strings in parallel fed by a CC driver then you have all the binning and temp problems to solve. Using a CCR is the simplest way to isolate all the strings. I much prefer constant voltage drive with string current defined for each string. This way it's easy to use either CCR or a small WiFi MCU to PWM the string. All controlled very simply very simply at the endpoint. The only folks that should be doing Serial and parallel groups of LEDs are the COB panel producers. It's not for DIY.

Comment: Temp problems with 20 mA LEDs?  I understand the parallel LED driven with a CC driver.  Samsung sells millions of strips (F-Series) with 8S8P  and 16S9P (F-Series 11" and 22"). I've been doing EE over 40 years and currently only do strips for horticulture where uniformity is very important.  In lighting uniformity is not that important as the eye cannot distinguish intensity as well as plants.  I buy a lot of 0.01Ω resistors. I test and monitor parallel strings a lot.  In this case, no problem with 4P5S with hi-efficacy Cree LEDs.  I think in production quantities, $1 for 1 PCB, not an issue.

Comment: I always respect your answers, you are one of the best here IMHO.  BTW, The first time I saw one of your answers it was regarding my testing of parallel strips with a CC driver.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340461/led-parallel-forward-voltage-higher-than-indvidual-leds-vf/340488#340488

Comment: I understand your perspective when manufacturing for quantities of product. I also liked the Osram app note ...BUT ….binning to balance currents in a matrix is hard. I would always coach folks to avoid it if possible. You do have matching and thermal problems even @20mA. It's surprising how hot strip LEDs can get. In the past I've made my own long series current controls, but the CCR's are just so much more convenient. If you look at the quantities in stock at Digikey you get an appreciation of the popularity of the devices. But to each their own favorite designs.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct for a constant voltage source, not a battery.  In practice, a lower battery voltage is stepped up to the required voltage level using a constant current (CC) boost LED driver.

The question should be how much battery capacity is required for twenty 20 mA LEDs for a specific length of time.

If the string is powered from a battery without a CC LED driver, the intensity will decrease as the battery discharges. If you used a 62V battery it would soon discharge to below the necessary voltage required to sufficiently illuminate the LEDs. When using a CCR the battery range gets to much with larger voltages (i.e over 6V).

---

After looking at boost CC drivers, I have concluded a 62V CC boost driver is too complex.

While you can boost a Li-ion battery to 62V, a 62V supply is not practical. A practical max boost voltage for an Li-ion battery is 40V. 
It would be best to use a serial/parallel combination of 4P5S. When selecting a serial parallel combination it is best to use the fewest in parallel.

There are issues with driving serial/parallel combinations with a CC driver but a 4P5S combination is fine with low and mid power LEDs.

OSRAM App Note: [Comparison of LED Circuits](https://www.ttiinc.com/content/dam/ttiinc/manufacturers/osram/pdf/Comparison-of-LED-circuits.pdf)
includes failure modes and trade offs.

4P5S would require a supply voltage of about 15V so an 18V<sup>1</sup> boost driver would be ideal. This is the boost circuit I would recommend using a TI [TPS61040 Low-Power DC-DC Boost Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61040.pdf).
Very simple and better than 80% efficiency.  You could also buy an off the shelf CC boost driver but it need to be optimized for low power.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> *The LEDs will operate at their actual <sub>f</sub> and not 18V.  So there is no wasted  power due to the voltage difference.*

---

**When you have a battery powered LED project the most important thing is to use the highest efficacy LED available.**

The average mcd output intensity for 240 unique red through hole 20 mA LEDs found on Digikey was 1066 mcd.  Half of them were under 500 mcd.

So let's we have a 5¢ (single qty) red battery powered 20 mA LED with a luminous intensity of 500 mcd.  Reasonable?

Compare this with a 16¢ (single qty) Cree [503B-RAS-CA0C0AA1](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/C503B-RAS-RAN-AAS-AAN-RBS-RBN-ABS-ABN-RCS-RCN-ACS-ACN-1079.pdf) 22450 mcd red LED.
To get 500 mcd from this LED it needs 445 µA (yes **micro** amp) or 45x less current.
A name brand CR2032 battery will cost close to $1.00.

By switching from the cheap eBay LED to the quality Cree LED that cost 10¢ more you saved $45 (running both LEDs the same time as the Cree LED).

Additionally when running the LED at half a mA the forward voltage drops significantly reducing the power (I x E).

Comment: It's still not clear to me what's the purpose of this led string. If it's decoration or indication or it's for lighting and area. In the first case you can count in mcd and limit the consumption to a very low level. In the second case you need to count lm (lumens) and it's a whole another story.

Comment: About cost: If it's for a single project you won't care whether you paid, for the same quantity, $3 for quality brand leds or $0.15 for no-brand leds on some china-based online portal. But if you need 100 times 20 leds, with this quantity, or be commercially viable, you may rethink the equation. Quality brands will give you a honest price if you place a factory order for one million pieces or so (preferably per month). But in semi-retail or small quantities they are just insanely expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you have to wire all your LEDs in series? 12 volt power supplies are much more prevalent and significantly easier to acquire than a 62V power supply (or 62V battery that would eventually discharge). And ideal wiring method would be to place 3x of these LEDs in series with a 12V power supply and a current limiting resistor (45 ohms to be exact, a 50ohm should work great). There are several key benefits to wiring them in this particular method:

- Uses a commonly found power supply, with current supply ratings of pretty much anything
- Protects the LEDs by limiting current to each set of 3
- Allows for the quick addition or subtraction of LEDs (keeping in mind your power supply current limits).

If you wire all 20 LEDs in series with a 62V power supply, this can cause problems down the line (pun intended). 20 LEDs, even if all made the same manufacturer, aren't perfectly the same, and they all have a tolerance. Before you know it, one poorly manufactured LED exceeds its limits and fries, and the entire system turns off. Now you are left with a string of 20 LEDs and you have no idea which one burnt out. (this was the problem with early day Christmas lighting).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Not correct. If you connect the LEDs in series the current through them MUST ABSOLUTELY be the same, no matter what the VF for an individual LED is.

Comment: Agreed, fixed that. However, there are still problems introduced with wiring a million LEDs in series

Comment: Care to explain this statement? "Before you know it, one poorly manufactured LED exceeds its limits and fries, and the entire system turns off." How exactly do you exceed the specifications of any LED in the series string.

Comment: There are tons of factors that can lead to failure to a diode, and I wasn't trying to be too technical on that ins and outs of them (also lots of the specifics are past my knowledge base). Basically I was trying to point out in laymen's terms that if one diode blows due to whatever (static, condensation, whatever), the entire system fails.

Comment: If one LED fails (you then need to define fail open vs fail short) all that happens if that the added Vf's drop by one Vf. If the string is feed by a CC source and one LED fails short ABSOLUTELY NOTHING happens. If any LED in the string fails open then the current is zero ...but still no catastrophe. No LED can be stressed beyond it characteristics.

Comment: Current limning resistors are not recommended for battery powdered LEDs due to the voltage range over the lifespan of the battery.  What is the difference in wiring in series vs. series/parallel?  There are not tons of ways for an LED to fail.  In the VERY rare case of a failure, it is almost always due to excessive heat.  How do you find the failed LED???  Simple troubleshooting!

Comment: If you read the answer I was not talking about using a 12 battery, I was talking about a 12V power supply which I stated 3 times to be exact. Yes, simple diagnostics will tell you which LED failed, but which is easier, individually investigating/testing 20 leds in a row, or testing 1 of 3 leds in a parallel configuration? Also, which is simpler, most likely a bit more efficient, and easier, 62V series with a step up or a 12V parallel config? I'm also curious as to when the author of the question is going to weigh in :)

Comment: Okay, so when you said 12V power supply you meant 12V battery?  Even at that, a battery and resistor is a very poor design.  Batteries are expensive and your solution is not efficient.  Batteries have a wide voltage range in their discharge cycle so the LED intensity and efficiency vary too much.  If you want to use a current liming device use a CCR not a resistor to keep the intensity constant.  But doing that you need a battery with a cutoff voltage above the Vf.  3 series LEDs powered with 12V is too inefficient for a battery.   You need 4 in series with 12V.

Comment: If you use batteries with resistors as current limiter, and one LED fails, then the voltage drop across the entire series drops, which means the current would increase. Won't that cause a cascade effect and potentially cause more failures?

Comment: @daniel which circuit are you referring to? 62V with 20 LEDs in series or 12V with 3 and a resistor? Remember, if one LED fails, the most likely scenario it will become an open circuit and no current will be able to flow through it. In fact I tested that 15 minutes ago with some LEDs (I had a lot of fun pumping 12V to one LED to watch it break ;)

Comment: @HavocRC thanks for the test and clarification. Didn't know failure mode of LED

Comment: I agree that generating 65V to power 20 leds in serie is not a good idea. It's better to split it into 5 series of 4 leds, each serie connected in parallel on a single 12V source. Each led will take 3V which is within range. Now if luminous intensity is not important (i.e. decoration, indicator etc) you can make 4 serie of 5 leds. they will not be as bright but you will save a lot of power being on battery. Or if the light is too low, 5 series of 4 on a 9V supply or something adjusted in between. This works very well with SMD leds, but very poorly with melon hat leds.

Comment: With 4 leds on 12V, theoricaly there is no need for a resistor thought it's good practice to add a 10 ohm resistor at every serie. But the resistor shouldn't dissipate as much power as if you tried to regulate 3 leds on 12V to reach 3.1V per led. Makes more sens to get 3V per led and no or very little resistor.

Comment: @Fredled yes agreed personally I'd give up the .1 volt with a small value resistor; it does save more power that way.